# Migrate data from azure data lake into azure sql using azure logicapps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

[image]

I need to create a logic app and my requirement is ,I need to migrate A json file from azure data lake Gen2 folder and based on some value need to convert that json into xml and then send it to SQL.

So based on my requirement i tried the workflow as shown in image but i am not sure whether my approach is wrong or right.

could you please provide in detail azure logic app workflow structure  for my requirement by providing in detail trigger and actions images and  expression.

Any early and detail response would be appreciated.

Comment: We’re not here to architect your solution. You need to come here with a problem. If your flow works, there’s no problem.

Comment: One question for sure would be; why dont you just use ADF which is specifically created for this purpose, instead of Logic Apps?

Comment: @Ziya Mert Karakas
 Thank you. But i can't go with ADF as i have to do it in Azure logic app only

Comment: @frezsha I didn't downvote your question, I don't do that.  You're asking for architectural advice though.  You haven't articulated what your issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are expected results :

**`Input:`**

```
{
"UserID":88888,
"FirstName":"Rithwik",
"LastName":"Bojja",
"Email":"rithwik@mail.com"
}
```

[image]

**`File in Azure Storage Account:`**

[image]

**`Design:`**

[image]

Then:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Code view for replication:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Get_blob_content_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['azureblob']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('AccountNameFromSettings'))}/files/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('JTJmcml0aHdpayUyZnRlc3R0Lmpzb24='))}/content",
                    "queries": {
                        "inferContentType": true
                    }
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "JTJmcml0aHdpayUyZnRlc3R0Lmpzb24=": "/rithwik/testt.json"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Insert_row_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Email": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['Email']",
                        "FirstName": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['FirstName']",
                        "LastName": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['LastName']",
                        "UserID": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['UserID']"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[Users]'))}/items"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@json( body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'))",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Email": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "FirstName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "LastName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "UserID": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_blob_content_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "azureblob": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/rbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/azureblob",
                    "connectionName": "azureblob",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/azureblob"
                },
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/rbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
                    "connectionName": "sql",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For insert row action i am not getting left side attributes like FirstName, Last Name etc.. and unable to fetch server name and data base name so i have given those manually. How to over come this

Comment: At down you will have an arrow like saying add parameters their you will find last name, first name like this https://i.imgur.com/eKphgHI.png.

Comment: @
RithwikBojja . getting this error while connecting to server Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again. Details: Microsoft SQL: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.) clientRequestId: 3ca79c34-e237-4591-8-***** More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is '90DD23C0-C2B8-4F35-A-*******'.

Comment: Read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure?tabs=consumption) on Sql server connector for clearing your error, follow this doc